# Firebase database not filling with values

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fill my firebase database but nothing is showing and i have no errors, my permissions are true in read and write

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {   
 
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val myRef = database.getReference("message")
    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
    Log.e("mytag", myRef.toString())
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  You're ignoring the result of setValue, so it could be failing, and you'd never know why.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Saving data with realtime firebase database

```
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
// ...
database = Firebase.database.reference
database.child("users").child().setValue("Hello, World!")
```